# Sleuth not propagating trace Id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Spring cloud Sleuth in Spring boot application.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.M8'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate template() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private LanguageService languageService;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @GetMapping(value="/{Id}")
    public Language getDetails(@PathVariable("Id") Integer Id) {

        LOG.info("Getting Details..");
        Language language = languageService.getLanguage(Id);
        SubLang SubLang = template.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/"+Id, SubLang.class);
        language.setSubLang(SubLang);

        return language;
    }

}
```

Now, when I hit the browser for sending the request, I want to get the trace Id which should be same in both the micro-service.

Below is the log for current micro-service.

```
INFO [HomeCont,b2a07f3e8f053b21,b2a07f3e8f053b21,false][0;39m [35m8524[0;39m
```

Below is the log for http://localhost:8081/ micro-service.

```
INFO [HomeLang,32b435aef0698cd6,32b435aef0698cd6,false] 10176
```

According to the concept, `b2a07f3e8f053b21` should be same as Trace Id in both the micro-service.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Here you have a working example https://github.com/openzipkin/sleuth-webmvc-example just follow the stpes done in the presented solution